# Flex unrecognised rule error

Tags: regex, flex-lexer, lexer

I am trying to use the following pattern in flex to match preprocessor information of the form `# linenum filename flags` but I am getting unrecognised rule error. This is the pattern that triggers it:

```
# [0-9]+ \"[^"]*\" [1-4]{0,4}
```

Comment: I think you need to quote the interior spaces, but you should parse this, not scan it.

Comment: Rules should be single-strings, no white-space in between, and literal characters should be quoted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved from comments:

White spaces need to be quoted for rules should have no whitespace in between

```
  PP_INFO #[ ][0-9]+[ ]\"[^"]*\"[ ][1-4]{0,4}
```